# Perl + dbd/mysql insert with loop data + exp reg

Tags: mysql, perl

Well, this is my question.

I need to insert data in the three tabblas nid, name, dir these are filtered from a file using regular expressions, and there are thousands, used a loop to do so in three in three.

content in file /home/lola/locatebookmarks

```
"date_added": "12988591842733282",
"id": "1706",
"name": "Xenode Systems Blog: \u00BFQu\u00E9 Hacer despu\u00E9s de instalar Fedora 15?",
"type": "url",
"url": "http://otrolink.com.ar/lola.html"
"date_added": "12988591842733884",
"id": "1707",
"name": "Install Google Chrome in Fedora 16 / 15 / 14 using YUM | HowOpenSource",
"type": "url",
"url": "http://www.howopenlola.com/2011/11/"
"date_added": "12988591842734487",
"id": "1708",
"name": "Linuxant - Linux drivers for Conexant chipsets - ALSA driver with improved support for Conexant chipsets",
"type": "url",
"url": "http://urlllola.com/alsa-driver/"
```

This code in perl.

```
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;

$host = "localhost";
$database = "bookmarks";
$tablename = "test";
$user = "lola";
$pwd = "pass";
$connect = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$database:$host", $user, $pwd);

open(FILE, '/home/lola/locatebookmarks');
my @array;
my $var;
while ($i = <FILE>) {
    if ($i =~ /(id|name|http)/) {
        if ($i =~ s/("|:|,|name|id|url)//g) {
            ($key) = $i;
            push(@array, $var);
        }
    }
}
close(FILE);

$n=@array;
$n=($n/=3);
$count = 0;

for ($x = 0; $x < $n; $x++)  {
    while ($count <= 3) {
        $nid = pop(@array);
        $nombre = pop(@array);
        $dir = pop(@array);

        $query_insert = "INSERT INTO $tablename (nid, nombre, dir) 
        VALUES ('$nid', '$nombre', '$dir')";
        $query = $connect->prepare($query_insert);
        $query->execute();

    $count++;
    }
}
```

in mysql save this, but that bad, because save "," !!

```
,                 Linuxant - Linux drivers for Conexant chipsets - ALSA driver with improved support for Conexant chipsets
,                 1708

,                 Install Google Chrome in Fedora 16 / 15 / 14 using YUM | HowOpenSource
,                 1707

,                 Xenode Systems Blog u00BFQuu00E9 Hacer despuu00E9s de instalar Fedora 15?
,                 1706

, ,
```

If change in VALUES in code perl.

```
('$nid', '$nombre', '$dir')"; > VALUES ('$nid' '$nombre' '$dir')";
```

Its error, in console.

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 at exp-b.pl line 38.
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 at exp-b.pl line 38.
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 at exp-b.pl line 38.
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 at exp-b.pl line 38.
```

I need in mysql.

```
        nid         nombre      dir

       1708         Linuxant - Linux drivers for Conexant chipsets - ALSA driver with improved support for Conexant chipsets    http://urlllola.com/alsa-driver/
       1707      Install Google Chrome in Fedora 16 / 15 / 14 using YUM | HowOpenSource     http://www.howopenlola.com/2011/11/
       1706         Xenode Systems Blog: \u00BFQu\u00E9 Hacer despu\u00E9s de instalar Fedora 15?       http://otrolink.com.ar/lola.html
```

I hope you understand , greetings

Comment: You should use [placeholders](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values) instead of using variables directly in the query. What if one of your variables contains an apostrofe? E.g. `'Joe's big problem'`.

Comment: Put in a print of $query_insert to see the exact SQL that is being executed. Also, do as TLP suggested with the placeholders.

Comment: Please, use `strict` and use `warnings`, attend to any errors, and then please post the complete code that you are *actually* running.  (As others noted, you don't ever set `$var`, etc.  Your second set of errors comes from interpolating a question mark into your SQL, but your "change in VALUES in code perl" isn't syntactically valid, etc.)

Comment: yeah, change (nid, nombre, dir) VALUES (?, ?, ?) but, everything is still equal , and but use strict and warnings? use::strict y use::warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this:

```
open(FILE, '/home/lola/locatebookmarks');
my @array;
my $var;
while ($i = <FILE>) {
    if ($i =~ /(id|name|http)/) {
        if ($i =~ s/("|:|,|name|id|url)//g) {
            ($key) = $i;
            push(@array, $var);
        }
    }
} 
close(FILE);
```

Never sets any value into $var, so when you push it onto @array, you're pushing nothing. So you probabaly want to push either $i onto @array and forget about $key.

This:

```
$n=($n/=3);
```

should probably be:

```
$n /= 3
```

and I second @TLP regarding using placeholders instead of variable interpolation in the SQL.

```
$query_insert = "INSERT INTO $tablename (nid, nombre, dir) 
VALUES ('$nid', '$nombre', '$dir')";
$query = $connect->prepare($query_insert);
$query->execute();
```

becomes:

```
$query_insert = "INSERT INTO $tablename (nid, nombre, dir) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$query = $connect->prepare($query_insert);
$query->execute($nid, $nombre, $dir);
```